# Should I place my HTML inside JS, and innerHTML to .root, just like React.js?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, simple-html-dom

Should I consider

HTML:

```
<div class="root"></div>
```

JS:

```
document.querySelector(`.root`). innerHTML = `{ **html here** }`;
```

Would this ease my work out make it even worse?

Comment: Why would you do this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

depends on the project. data heavy stuff generating html from js is the way to go... for more static sites, html is just fine.

I generally don't write more html than this.

```
<body id="root"></body>
<script>
const root = document.getElementById('root');
</script>
```